# How to check if a kernel module is inserted or not in c?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

Is it possible to check if kernel module is inserted or not in C language without using system()

for example:

```
system(lsmod | grep ixgbe)
```

Comment: Yes, because the `lsmod` program is itself (almost surely) written in C, so whatever it does, you can do in your program. `strace lsmod` to find out what it does.

Comment: It opens /proc/modules and just reformats the output, line-by-line.

Comment: Check the source for `lsmod`. It uses `/proc`: https://superuser.com/questions/230858/do-both-lsmod-and-proc-modules-use-the-same-mechanism-to-retrieve-modules

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, there's a module interface you can use directly from C.  See this:</strike>

http://linux.die.net/man/2/query_module

Nope - that's not it.  Try reading from /sys/module/[NAME]/initstate.  You should get something back like "live\n" if the module is loaded.

Comment: Not on any modern system. "This system call is only present on Linux up until kernel 2.4; it was removed in Linux 2.6."